# Setting up an Email alert on "crontab" for SOME tasks

Tags: cron, email

I am using crontab to run tasks automatically on my Ubuntu headless server (php, sh, python files).
I like to keep track of the error logs to see if something went wrong during the execution.
I set up an Email alert (using MAILTO="<my_Email>") and it is working great. I do have access to the logs and it is keeping me updated just the way I wanted.

The only issue I am experiencing is that I have a cron job which is set to run every 15 minutes or so, and I am not interested in seeing the logs. It also pollutes my Mailbox by sending notifications every 15 minutes.

Is there a way to set up an Email alert for some specific cron tasks (not all of them)?

Thank you!

Comment: If your cron job is not producing any output, it should not send any mail. At least it always worked so for me. So make your cron task "silent", don't write anything to stdout or stderr, and you probably shouldn't get any mail from that job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in `man 5 crontab`:

> The crontab file is parsed from top to bottom, so any environment
> settings will affect only the cron  commands  below  them  in  the
> file.

So you can simply set `MAILTO=""` (empty string) immediately before the task that you don't want alerts from, then back to `MAILTO="<my_Email>"` if you had later jobs that should send alerts.

Comment: Good! I didn't know that.

Comment: A straightforward answer. I like it. Thank you so much!

Comment: In case it wasn't clear to others, the syntax is `MAILTO=""` instead of `MAILTO=`

Comment: @evencoil thank you - I was confusing crontab syntax and shell syntax for the assignment